# Is there a limit to the number of times a question is eligible to vote on to reopen after it has been edited?

Tags: support, status-completed, editing, review-queues, closed-questions

I'm asking this question because when I have voted on a reopen request on a question that I subsequently voted to remain close, because of insufficient changes to the original question.

So does that mean the anytime an edit occurs on a post that is closed will be sent to the reopen voting option for review?

I haven't found a previous question that answers this question.

I think it's great that a user or users would keep making edits, as necessary, to improve a post to help get an answer in the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to go looking for what I think is the answer to this:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue/256572#256572

I think what @Shog9 is saying at the above link is that, if a question is closed, then it can only be placed in the re-open queue once.  After eligible users vote for it to be left closed or re-opened the outcome will be:

- question remains closed and editing alone will not put it back into the re-open queue.  I think this is to discourage askers from making minor edits and hoping that will be enough for re-opening rather than heavily revising to give their question a reasonable chance to have addressed the issues that lead to the close votes.
- question re-opened.  If it later gets closed again then edited, then it gets another chance to be fed through the re-open queue.

So, in @Shog9's words the limit is that:

> A question will only be enqueued once per closure via editing. It will
>   be enqueued once per reopen vote as long as there are no outstanding
>   reopen votes that've already triggered a review.

There is more background/information to @Shog9's answer at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/215590

---

There is a feature request at Meta Stack Exchange that may help to alleviate this: [Let reviewers know if a suggested edit will push the question into the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307590/let-reviewers-know-if-a-suggested-edit-will-push-the-question-into-the-reopen-qu) - I have upvoted it.

Answer (score 4):

One specific point written in [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue/256572#256572) I'd like to emphasize is:

> A question will only be enqueued once per closure via editing.

**If a question is put on hold I try to avoid editing it, if the edit will not contribute for reopening that question**. For example, removing 'thanks' or removing superfluous introductory noise to a question which was put on hold as unclear. If it is unclear it needs more information, or edition of existing content. In most cases, only OP can provide it.

Therefore, I believe doing such edits will have a contrary effect, i.e., will contribute to maintain the on hold status.

This is because the 'on hold' question will automatically be sent to the queue after being firstly edited, won't be reopened due to the edit being unrelated to the close reason, and if the OP later decides to substantially improve his/her own post the system won't send it a second time to the review queue.

Comment: For the same reason I try to always remove thanks, other chit chat, spelling mistakes, confusing grammar, etc from a question body and make its title more concise **before** voting to close.